# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^3x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I need to find where in $\mathbb{R}$ the following series converges absolutely and where it converges uniformly:
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+n^3x}$$
I know by the M-test that both conditions are satisfied when $x>0$ simply from the bound $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{n^3}$. For $x = 0$, neither are possible, as the series diverges there.

But for $x < 0$, I do not how to find a bound on the $f_n(x)$. I've tried reverse triangle inequality and expanding $f_n$ in series, but this does not help, and also I do not know where the series even converges for these values of $x$. Is M-test still the correct approach?

Comment: The series is not even  defined for $x=-1$, for example. The denominator is $0$ when $n=1$.

Comment: More generally the series is not defined for all $x$ of the form $-1/n^3$.

Comment: Your conclusion of uniform convergence for all $x>0$ is not correct. As you say there is no convergence when $x=0$, but also there is no uniform convergence on any interval where $0$ is an endpoint or just a limit point , such as $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weierstrass M-test does imply uniform convergence on any interval $[a,\infty)$ where $a > 0$ since

$$|f_n(x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{1+n^3a},$$

and the series with terms given by the RHS is convergent.

However, the convergence is not uniform for all $x  >0$  since $f_n(x) =  \frac{1}{1+ n^3x}$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $(0,\infty)$. This is evident because

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}|f_n(x)| = f_n(0) =1 \underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow1 \neq 0$$

Alternatively, we see that

$$\sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k^3x}\right|= \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k^3x}\geqslant \sup_{x \in (0,\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{1+k^3x} \\\geqslant n \cdot \frac{1}{1+(2n^3)\cdot n^{-1/3}}= \frac{n}{3}\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow +\infty \neq 0$$

For $x \in (-\infty,-a]$ where $-a < -1$, we can again apply the Weierstrass M-test to find uniform convergence, since $x \leqslant -a < -1$ and $1+n^3x \leqslant 1-n^3a < 1 - n^3$. This implies that $|1+n^3x| \geqslant n^3a-1 >0 $

$$|f_n(x)| = \frac{1}{|1+n^3x|} \leqslant \frac{1}{n^3a -1} = \mathcal{O}(n^{-3})$$

Try to finish by considering when $x \in [-1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I believe now, in addition to the intervals $[a,\infty)$, we have uniform convergence on any interval $(-\infty,-a]$ modulo the points where the series becomes undefined; $\{x = -\frac{1}{n^3} | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. $|f_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{n^3} \frac{1}{a-1/n^3} \leq \frac{2}{an^3}$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: @Integralfan: You're welcome.  That sounds correct.